# Problem with VLC minimal X theme on freya OS

Tags: themes, vlc

i have installed VLC and I want to use this theme : 
[VLC - MinimalX by Maverick07x on DeviantArt](http://maverick07x.deviantart.com/art/VLC-MinimalX-385698882)

When I choose the theme from preferences its ok and the theme changes but the problem is when I want to view playlist or change sound volume after clicking on the icon it will open the playlist in another window

Like if you press <kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> key you will see two instances of VLC 1 is the main vlc app and the other is just the playlist window

**NOTE:**I tested this theme on Ubuntu 15 and Windows And it works find when you click on playlist icon it does not open another window

Comment: This is possibly an issue with the newer Gtk defaults.

Comment: @Lewis Goddard do you have any solutions ?

Comment: Probably not I'm afraid, since it's a third party issue I don't know much about. Does the issue persist if you reset VLC to its to defaults?

Comment: no it works fine after i change to native skin, same problem exists with other vlc themes too...

Comment: All "other" VLC themes, or just some of them? If it's all of them, it's likely the theming engine, if not then it's likely an outdated or bugged theme.

Comment: i tryed to more themes and the result is the same ...

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer is probably that you should not use this theme. You may want to seek help from a VLC specific forum. Generally if a specific app is doing something odd, it's the fault of that app. In this case, it's only with a specific mod to that specific app. So that theme is probably just not compatible.